# I can't browse the pages Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Web-scraping and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/) to extract movie data from [this link](https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2016-01-01,2019-05-01), I chose to extract movies between 2016 and 2019 for the test. I get just 25 lines but I want more than 30000.
Do you think it's possible ?

this is the code :

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from time import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,5)]
years_url = [str(i) for i in range(2000,2018)]

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2016-01-01,2019-05-01'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')

names = []
years = []
imdb_ratings = []
metascores = []
votes = []
start_time = time()
requests = 0

for year_url in years_url:
# For every page in the interval 1-4
   for page in pages:
# Make a get request
      response = get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=' + year_url +'&sort=num_votes,desc&page=' + page, headers = headers)
# Pause the loop
      sleep(randint(8,15))
# Monitor the requests
      requests += 1
      elapsed_time = time() - start_time
 print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
clear_output(wait = True)
# Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
if response.status_code != 200:
  warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))
# Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
  if requests > 72:
    warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')

# Parse the content of the request with BeautifulSoup
page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# Select all the 50 movie containers from a single page
mv_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')

# Extract data from individual movie container
for container in movie_containers:
# If the movie has Metascore, then extract:
  if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None:
# The name
   name = container.h3.a.text
   names.append(name)
# The year
   year = container.h3.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
   years.append(year)
# The IMDB rating
   imdb = float(container.strong.text)
   imdb_ratings.append(imdb)
# The Metascore
   m_score = container.find('span', class_ = 'metascore').text
   metascores.append(int(m_score))
# The number of votes
   vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
   votes.append(int(vote))


   movie_ratings = pd.DataFrame({'movie': names,
  'year': years,
  'imdb': imdb_ratings,
  'metascore': metascores,
  'votes': votes
  })

#data cleansing
movie_ratings = movie_ratings[['movie', 'year', 'imdb', 'metascore', 'votes']]
movie_ratings.head()
movie_ratings['year'].unique()
movie_ratings.to_csv('movie_ratings.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by double checking your indentation through out (in fact - naughty naughty - it is wrong in that tutorial. I am guessing it wasn't properly proof read after publishing and the code has wrongly been left aligned repeatedly).

To illustrate, you currently have something like (reduced lines of code shown)

```
for year_url in years_url:
    for page in pages:
        response = get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=' + year_url +'&sort=num_votes,desc&page=' + page, headers = headers)

page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Your indentation means, if code runs at all, you are only working with last url you intended to visit in terms of actual html parsing.

It should be:

```
for year_url in years_url:
    for page in pages:
        response = get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=' + year_url +'&sort=num_votes,desc&page=' + page, headers = headers)
        page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

**Indentation gives meaning in python**.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=indentation

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what the issue is here because of the lack of functions but from what I see, you need to parse each page separately.

After every request, you need to parse the text. However, I suspect the main issue is the ordering of your code, I would suggest using functions.